# Scanf function not waiting for string input

Tags: c, string, scanf

In this code , after giving inputs for the first two scanf functions . the output is automatically shown . I learned this form of scanf for string. But it does not wait specifically for it . Any suggestions ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    int q;
    char kog[50];

    scanf("%d",&p);
    scanf("%d",&q);
    scanf("%50[^ ]s",kog);

    printf("%d %d %s",p,q,kog);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for interactive input read *lines*.

Comment: Your scan set will allow tabs and newlines but not blanks.  It is similar to `%50s`.  Also, you must specify a length excluding the null byte, so you need to use `49` and not `50` in the format (or change the array dimension to `51`) to be safe.  The off-by-one is historical and hence sacrosanct, but unfortunately inconsistent with most other functions that specify a buffer length.  If the numbers are on separate lines, you probably want a space before the scan set (`" %49[^ ]"`) to skip the newline left by the prior `%d`.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%50[^ ]s",kog);`  the function `scanf()` for a char string input will always append a NUL byte, so the statement should be: `scanf("%49[^ ]s",kog);`.  Also, the `[...] acts to input a string, so the trailing `s` should not be there  I.E. use: `scanf("%49[^ ]",kog);`

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by:

```
scanf("%50[^ ]s",kog);
```

?

If you want to scan till new line is printed, try:

```
scanf(" %49[^\n]",kog);
```

And by the way always mention width specifier 1 less than the size of the string. This is to avoid overwriting the terminating null character. So mention 49 instead of 50 as width specifier.

From [**cppreference**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

> If width specifier is used, matches only up to width. Always stores a null character in addition to the characters matched (so the argument array must have room for at least width+1 characters).

Also, note that a scan set conversion is complete at the `]`. the structure is `"%49[…]"` and that's all. It is a common misapprehension that the scan set should be followed by `s`.

And provide a space before `%` in the `scanf()` to avoid consuming the new line character entered at the end of previous entry.

Comment: Yeah, i already mentioned a space in the scanf `scanf(" %49[^\n]",kog);` to avoid consuming the new line. I've added info about it :)

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number. I.E. 50.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Suggest giving the 'magic' numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: a much better code sequence would be: `#define MAX_STR_LEN 49 .... char kog[ MAX_STR_LEN+1]; ... scanf(" %" MAX_STR_LEN "[^ ]",kog);`

Comment: Actually, the width needs to be one less than the actual length of the input buffer, so that the call to `scanf()` does not write beyond the end of the input buffer.